# how to get list of subscribers for a particular channel on pubnub

Tags: titanium-mobile, publish-subscribe, pubnub

I am writing an application in titanium by making use of pubnub. I need to get the device id or any specific details of all people who are subscribed to a particular channel. Please let me know how do I get the device id of all sudcribers to a particular channel.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such function in the whole Documentation of Pubnub.
You have to implement a function like "whosthere()" which posts a message to a Channel. All connected (subscribed) clients then need to answer to that Post with "imhere()" or something similar.

- http://www.pubnub.com/devcenter

Comment: thanks for that... I need some more help please.. If say two clients reply with 'imhere' then how to connect to any one particular client among the two..?